# Shouldn't people be notified when a voted upon answer is later edited?

Tags: feature-request, editing, voting, notifications

This one's been bugging me for a while.

Many times, people will vote on my answers, and then I'll edit it afterwards.

They should be notified when I edit it, so that they can choose to see if they still agree with their vote, in light of the changes made to the answer (or question).

Unless I'm missing something, at the moment the only way to tell if the answer was changed is to go to the page and see if it's been edited since you voted on it.

Answer (score 1):

[A proposal for even less of a change to the status quo, but along the same lines,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751) [has been declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52628/161792).

Comment: They declined a Jon Skeet request???

Comment: Not to mention, look how unpopular that Jeff Atwood response is! 18 downvotes on a founder's post.

Comment: @HodofHod "The community isn't always right" - [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/12/building-social-software-for-the-anti-social.html). His answers on MSO always get attention, naturally, since they indicate what's most likely to actually get implemented, and people who disagree are inclined to fight back with the method they have. [Result](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=146).

Comment: But that proposal was just about downvotes. I can understand why it would be denied since we want to minimize commentless downvotes.

Comment: That proposal was to notify downvoters only, and you want to notify all voters: like I said, it's even more of a change. I see what you're saying, though: maybe they'd deny that but grant this. It's possible, yes. I doubt it, but obviously the SE folks will have the last word on this proposal.